# Android, ActionBar hiding other widgets

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Disclaimer: It's build with CLI only tools, so certainly some "auto-generated lines" are missing

It's a small application with a `MainActivity`  with a `EditText` and a `Button`

It works fine, but if I extends now from `ActionBarActivity` now my EditText and Button are hidden behind the Action Bar

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html The android documentation does not state about changes needing to be made in the layout.xml nor does the Training guide from which my application is based on

My MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // adding these lines show that the widget are correctly added
        //ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        //actionBar.hide();
    }
}
```

My main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enter_verb"
        android:hint="@string/enter_verb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <Button
        android:text="@string/button_conjugate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

My guess would be that I need to add something in my layout to make it aware there's a Action Bar, but I can't find anywhere what it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange, I've added the line coming from this link
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html

Which is:

`android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"`

in my LinearLayout tag, and then recompiled, after that the widget were shown but with a padding of the size of the actionBar in addition to the actionBar itself.

I then removed the line, recompiled and it now works as expected

A bug because of temporary files?